# How to use web2py form in a chat bot

Tags: html, web2py

Web2py Form comes with its own structure including the submit button. But how can one use it in a chat bot where messages are picked from text input e.g.:

Comment: The `FORM` helper does not include its own submit button, though `SQLFORM` does. In any case, your question is unclear. Please explain more precisely what you are trying to do and show the code you have tried so far.

Comment: in html input e.g. <input type="name" id="name" placeholder="Type message here" /> will post a message to view page immediately on click but not to sqlite db. The same to form, which stores input message to db. But in my question, i cant use it to chat and at the same time store the messages in sqlite. Am only familiar with a bit of html, web2py and python here. I tried stuff with this link but got no where: https://blog.vilourenco.com.br/como-criar-sqlite-offline-em-dispositivos-moveis-com-html5/